# How do I find the week number in a month

Tags: c#, .net

I need to find week number in a month. It could be 4 or 5 weeks in a month (depending on the calendar) and I need to find the week number based on the current date. 
Note : (Day)/7  would not work since Week 1 or Week 4 would be assumed to have 7 days which is not always the case.

Comment: What u have tried?

Comment: You may want to read Raymond Chen's discussions about week numbers. This is a good place to start https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160311-00/?p=93144

Answer (score 0):

Set the count to 1, and enumerate every day of a month. Add to count by 1 for each sunday except the first day. After the enumeration, the count is the number of weeks in that month.

Answer (score 0):

just do like this

```
DateTime date =DateTime.Now;
int weekOfMonth=(date.Day + ((int)date.DayOfWeek)) / 7 + 1;
```

calculation based on Malaysia time is (today number is 13 + day of week is 2) divided by `7` and then add `one` to result so result would be `3`